# shell script load average cpu

Tags: shell, cpu-usage

i need some help, i have this script (copy from google):

```
!/bin/bash
cpuuse=$(cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print int($1)}')
if [ "$cpuuse" > 75 ]; then
        SUBJECT="ALERTA: Uso de CPU $(hostname) at $(date)"
        MESSAGE="/tmp/Mail.out"
        TO="xxx@mail.com"
        echo "Uso CPU actual: $cpuuse%" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "+------------------------------------------------------------------+" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "Top CPU Process Using top command" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "+------------------------------------------------------------------+" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "$(top -bn1 | head -20)" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "+------------------------------------------------------------------+" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "Top CPU Process Using ps command" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "+------------------------------------------------------------------+" >> $MESSAGE
        echo "$(ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,fname | sort -k 1 -r | head -10)" >> $MESSAGE
        mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO" < $MESSAGE
        rm /tmp/Mail.out
fi
```

the problem is the condition "("$cpuuse" > 75)" never is true (values lower than 75) but anyway the mail is send.

Thanks

Best Regards

Comment: `>` compares strings in bash. Sure you want to do that instead of comparing integer values?

Comment: Also, `#!/bin/bash`, not `!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Running your script through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will give other suggestions and issues.

Comment: `>` has to be escaped in `[...]`, or it's considered a redirection. To compare numbers, you want to use `-gt` (or `>` and `((...))`). You probably have an empty file name `75` somewhere now.

Comment: but how do i do that?

Comment: thanks, i check and will try again